Wireless lav mic
I'm looking to record ASMR food content but I don't want a condenser or boom mic. Any option for wireless lav mic that picks up low db like chewing or crunching?

Do you know what frequency and SPL you are seeking to record?  Lav's usually roll off the low end to balance bass boost from the chest.
